# Spring / Hibernate - DB results to a log file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I can log the sql and input parameters by creating loggers for `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql`.

However is it possible to log the actual db results?
I am on spring with a hibernate db.

Additionally is it possible in spring to log the Database host?

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.SQL   - set to debug to log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.type -enter code here- set to trace to log all JDBC parameters
Change in hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
```

then in log4.properties :

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE

log4j.appender.hb=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.hb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```